# Rust -- how to return a value from a HashMap

Tags: rust

Here's a small function:

```
pub fn test_return_value() -> Box<dyn RoomInterface> {
    let mut r = HashMap::<String, Box<dyn RoomInterface>>::new();
    // blah blah blah, do stuff with the HashMap
    r.get("test_key").unwrap()
}
```

This doesn't compile and says:

```
37 |     pub fn test_return_value() -> Box<dyn RoomInterface> {
   |                                   ---------------------- expected `Box<(dyn room::RoomInterface + 'static)>` because of return type
38 |         let mut r = HashMap::<String, Box<dyn RoomInterface>>::new();
39 |         r.get("test_key").unwrap()
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `Box`, found reference
```

What does this error mean? How do I return a value that is stored in a HashMap?

Comment: Now it says "expected named lifetime parameter". If I add one, it says "cannot return value referencing local variable `r`". I'm still wrapping my head about this lifetime thing -- what to do in this specific case?

Comment: This can't work as posted. You are creating the HashMap inside the function and returning a reference to a value inside that HashMap when returning. The HashMap gets destroyed upon return, which would create a dangling reference in form of the return value. The compiler will prevent this, even if you fix the syntax error.

Comment: Let's take a step back. `HashMap::get` gives you an optional reference to a value in the hash map. You can't return that as an owned `Box`, since you don't own it - the hash map does. Returning a reference also won't work, because although now you're not trying to steal ownership, the thing you're referencing doesn't live long enough. You either need to `remove` the item from the hashmap and take ownership, or the hashmap needs to live long enough for the caller to use it. It's not clear which you are going for.

Comment: Can I clone the value in a HashMap somehow? Is there really no way for this to conceptually work?

Comment: GManNickG, using remove instead of get helped. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Using `remove` instead of `get` helped